# cannot print content of python dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to print the content of Python dictionary which is converted from JSON Object . I am unable to do that . Please help me , i don't know whats going wrong .
Edit : Please put some light why nothing is printed after "1 1 1 1 1" . What i need to add there to print il's value .

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import json
import cgi
import cgitb
import demjson





print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
print
print """\
<html>
    <head>
        <title>First Python HTTP Programming </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/python/cgi-bin/CSS/style.css" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/python/cgi-bin/Scripts/newpage1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Our Answer...</h1>
         </body>
</html>

"""




for i in range(6):
    print "1"

data = json.loads(sys.stdin)
il = data['lat']
#print "Content-type : application/json \n\n"


print il

print "2"
```

Thats my Python script . When i redirect to this script through a Ajax code (POST) using Jquery i get output till "1 1 1 1 1" nothing after that . I want to print value of il also in the screen . Please help me out .

This is my ajax query.

```
$(function()
        {
            $('#clickme').click(function(){
                alert('Im going to start processing');

                $.ajax({
                    url: "/city/cgi-bin/test1.py",
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    datatype:"json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({'lat':30.5 , 'lon' : 4.5}),
                    success: function(response){
                        window.location="http://mycity.parseapp.com/city/cgi-bin/test1.py";


                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Not entirely clear what you are asking. It seems the actual question is "How to pipe output form some ajax query to another python script so it can be read from stdin?"

Comment: How to print il in my code ? This is my question .Thats not getting printed when i redirect to this python script using window.location as written in ajax function .

Comment: The question is, _why_ is it not being printed. The print function surely works (it worked before in your code), so the problem is that either the program hangs at that points (because there is nothing on stdin to read from) or it finished reading before there is anything to read. You surely can understand that it's hard for us to reproduce your problem without your exact setup. Try to narrow down the problem, then come again with a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `json.load` instead of `json.loads`. `load` reads from a stream; `loads` reads from a string (hence the `s`).